# How do I get rid of this leading space highlighting in Nano (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, nano, syntax-highlighting

Here's an image:

[image]

Every time I type something with a leading tab, I get this obnoxious green/teal background until I type a value in for that line.

Also, for some reason on line 27, the color I entered is also highlighted with the green/teal background (It's not whitespace, yet still gets highlighting like it is)

Other lines with trailing whitespace also gets the same treatment.

How can I get rid of this? I don't want any of this whitespace highlighting.

Any help would be greatly, greatly, appreciated.

### Edit:

I deleted the offending line and still have the issue:

[image]

Comment: Since your attention is already on line 27... Look closely at it again. Does the regex ring any bells?

Comment: have you explored the nanorc part of the manual? https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.8/nanorc.5.html

Comment: Yes. I think what I don't understand is what syntax file to edit for dotfiles, such as `.nanorc`, or `.bash_profile`, etc. I am not getting where the green highlight is coming from after browsing all the `.nanorc` files in `~/.nano`. There is no `default.nanorc` that I can find.

Comment: Also, I'm specifically commenting out all includes, so I have no clue where the highlight is coming from.

Comment: @fmotion1 they might still be included from `/etc/nanorc`

Comment: @muru That was it! Thank you. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept as solution.

Comment: @fmotion1 since I don't know what was in your `/etc/nanorc`, it's probably better if you post an answer describing the problematic parts

Answer (score 2):

The problem is precisely that line 27 you mention. You are editing nano's configuration file, and you have a line there that says:

```
color ,green "[[:space:]]+$"
```

This is telling nano that it should color any occurrence of one or more whitespace characters before the end of the line (i.e. trailing whitespace) in green. Since an empty line with nothing but a tab or spaces is, by definition, trailing whitespace, that is why you see the color. Just delete that line and you will no longer have the issue.

Note that your file also brings in settings from other places with the `include` lines:

```
include /usr/share/nano/*.nanorc
include "~/.nano/*.nanorc"
```

This means that any settings in those files will also be applied and you may therefore need to comment those lines out or edit the included files.

Comment: I feel stupid for not realizing that. Thank you. I deleted the line you mention yet still whitespace is being highlighted. Is there any way to turn this off? See original post for a screenshot.

Comment: @fmotion1 you need to delete the line, save the file, then close nano and open a new Nani instance. Does it still happen after that?

Comment: Yes it does. But I found the answer after reading @muru's comment. Syntax highlighting was being imported from `/etc/nanorc`. I commented out all the imports in this file, and it no longer occurs. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Fair enough, @fmotion1, I added a relevant sentence to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Steps that fixed my problem:

1. Edit `~/.nano/nanorc.nanorc` and comment out the last line for Trailing whitespace: `icolor ,green "[[:space:]]+$"` > `## icolor ,green "[[:space:]]+$"`
2. Also comment out `icolor brightnormal " brightnormal"` > `## icolor brightnormal " brightnormal"` as it causes an error.
3. Open `/etc/nanorc` and check if it has additional highlighting includes. Mine had `include /usr/share/nano-syntax-highlighting/*.nanorc`
4. If the answer to the above is yes, edit `/usr/share/nano-syntax-highlighting/nanorc.nanorc` and comment out the same lines from steps 1 and 2.

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Note that any edits to files in `/usr` will be lost when the package is updated.

Comment: @muru Got it! Thank you.